# docker run says "No such image"

Tags: linux, docker, sudo

I have just installed docker on a linux server.

When I do any `sudo docker run` statement it always returns "No such image".

For example :

```
$ sudo docker run hello-world
Pulling repository hello-world
2017/09/29 05:28:48 Error: No such image: hello-world
```

**Why can docker not find the image ?**

Comment: Post `docker images`

Comment: Have you tried without the sudo?

Comment: @user2915097 - there are no images - however the behaviour I expect is that it will say `Unable to find image 'hello-world' locally` and then attempt to pull it

Comment: @GustavoMagalhães I installed it using sudo and so if I run `docker` without sudo it says "permission denied"

Comment: In order to use docker without sudo, you need to add the user to the group. Please refer to this https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo

Comment: have you logged into Docker's registry?

Answer (score 0):

Please start the docker with the below command:
$ sudo service docker start

Post start of docker verify with:
$ sudo docker run hello-world

Comment: It says "start: Job is already running: docker", and the $ sudo docker run hello-world statement returns the same as before, as in the question

Answer (score 0):

You should pull or create an image named "hello-world".

Comment: The documentation (https://docs.docker.com/get-started/#setup) and also my successful attempts on my Mac suggest that this command should just work; when the image is not found locally it goes to the docker cloud and downloads the image "hello-world" and then runs it -- but this doesn't happen on ubuntu